# Android find Bluetooth never visibility timeout

Tags: android, bluetooth, visibility

Is there a way to find if Bluetooth visibility is set to 'never timeout' state?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
BluetoothAdapter ba = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if (ba.getScanMode() != BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE)
{
    Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 0);           
    startActivity(discoverableIntent);
}
```

You should also make sure that the Adapter is turned on.

Comment: But this condition will be executed even when Visibility timeout is set to 2 minutes, 5 minutes or 1 hour. I was keen to know only when visibility timeout set to 'never timeout'.